# a:visited is not working on mozilla but works fine on IE

Tags: css

a:visited function works fine on my IE but not on mozilla. It has no effect on Mozilla. Css class is

```
            ul#menu1 li a:link, a:visited { 
    display: block; height: 18px; padding: 5px 0 6px 15px;
    text-decoration: none; clear: both; color: #666; 
             }
```

Comment: What version of Firefox?

Comment: I am using mozilla 3.6.14, so i read it somewhere that versions above 3.6.12 doesnt support the visited feature because of security reasons.Is it true?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `visited` style has been removed from Firefox (and most other browsers) in recent versions due to a security issue with it.

The problem is that a malicious web site could work out your browsing history by using it - they would set a `visited` colour, produce a load of URLs (even hidden ones so the user doesn't know about it), and check their colour. It caused quite a bit of noise in browser security circles a couple of years ago.

The `visited` feature can be switched back on again in Firefox, by going to the security preferences, but it is disabled by default, and most users will have it switched off.

See here for more info on the problem and how Firefox went about fixing it: http://blog.mozilla.com/security/2010/03/31/plugging-the-css-history-leak/

Comment: Now it seems layout.css.visited_links_enabled=true by default

Comment: @yakunins - since this answer was written, the solution to the problem has changed: previously they simply disabled the visited style; now they enable it so the link will be shown with the visited colour, but trying to read the colour via javascript will report the unvisited colour. So there are still limitations to this feature due to the security issue.

Comment: @Spudley I believe you'll find you can only change a few style elements... Eg you can't do anything that would change the size/position/layout at all as a malicious user could check the position of an element next to the link.

Answer (score 4):

Try changing your order so that it is :link, :visited, :hover, :active

Also ensure that your Mozilla options are set to remember your browsing history. If it doesn't remember the history, it can't know what you have visited or not.

Edit: It doesn't look like Mozilla has disabled the ability to differentiate visited links, but it appears that they have limited what properties you can use. See [here](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/) for more details.

Comment: It is the same as above.I am using mozilla 3.6.14, so i read it somewhere that versions above 3.6.12 doesnt support the visited feature because of security reasons.Is it true?

Comment: @user515990, a quick google search showed that they still support the feature, just in a limited capacity. See update.

Comment: Oh, is it, I tried to search for the link, pls share incase you have it with you.

Answer (score 1):

just make your selector more specific

```
ul#menu1 li a:link, ul#menu1 li a:visited { 
  //code here  
}
```

Note that I added `ul#menu1 li` in front of **a:visited**

what you have at the moment doesn't specify that the **a:visited** in question is the one inside the **ul#menu1 li** tag

Answer (score 0):

Try to change you selector like that:

```
#menu1 a:link, #menu1 a:visited { ... }
```

It should apply the css for all a:visited or a:link in the element where the id is menu1