# Stop blinking link once visited

Tags: css, hyperlink

How to stop blinking link once it clicked?
I want something like,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
a:link    {text-decoration: blink;}
a:visited {text-decoration: none;}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<a target="_blank" href="www.google.com">Click here!</a>

</body>
</html>
```

But it is not stopping blinking effect.

Comment: Seriously, you're using `blink`???? Please don't -- your visitors will hate you for it.

Comment: However, the actual answer to your problem is likely to be the issue described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221619/avisited-is-not-working-on-mozilla-but-works-fine-on-ie/5222282#5222282

Comment: Please mention the browser your are using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should use Javascript or CSS3 animations. `text-decoration: blink;` is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Please note that [IE, Chrome, Opera and Safari don't support this attribute](http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/text-decoration%3ablink).

Comment: Not to mention that a blinking link is considered bad design.

Comment: I like how MDN lists only that one as `non-standard,deprecated,obsolete`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration

Comment: @dan1111 : I totally agree with you, but the author maybe already knows that, and has to do it for his job for example.

Comment: @mimipc, agreed.  Not intended as a criticism of your good answer, just an additional comment.